# $this -> syntax in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-hmvc

I am fairly new to CodeIgniter framework and PHP, and I am trying to figure out what the following source code does:

```
isset($this->page->data->Metadata->Metadata->View);
```

From my understanding, `isset()` checks if the variable `View` is set or not, but what confuses me is that I couldn't find `page` class (the location of the .php file that contains `View` variable) anywhere in my project folder, nor can I find `page` class in the CodeIgniter libraries.

Can someone break down this code, and explain it in detail?

Comment: Please do not use backticks for emphasis. That's not what they're there for. See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text)

Comment: See [CodeIgniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/toc.html) and [PHP Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/index.php).

Answer (score 4):

You should really start to learn basic OOP (Object-Oriented Programming).

The `->` operator in PHP is a way to access member variables and member functions/methods of a class.
`$this` referes to the object, in which it's accessed. In your case, I guess, the your controller or model.  `$this` referes to your controller now.

Now you may wonder, where is `page`, because you cannot see it in your controller. Your controller is extending the Base controller of the codeigniter framework and there the member variable `page` is definied.
The variable `page` itself is an object which has the member variable `data` declared and `data` holds an object as well and this has the member variable `Metadata` and this...

You get the idea, I hope.

And the complete statement checks if a the `View` member variable is set on the object stored in the variable `Metadata`.

If you didn't understand any of this. You should read the very basics of PHP and OOP in general and in context of PHP! It's worth it. Trust me!